Ranking and unranking of a binary subset
Let's consider "N" bits.
We want to rank and unrank a specific subset of bit combinations based on the following criteria -
The number of consecutive 0s must be minimum "k" or more (k<N).

How can we rank (and unrank) only based on the given bit combination (and not by iterating the full range of 2^N bits). This will be efficient for large N bits.
I tried the following approach  -
Example with N=5 and k=3

Start from LSB bit (position 1), and count the number of possible combinations with >=3 consecutive 0s:

Position 1 - 0 >=3 consecutive 0s
Position 2 - 0 >=3 consecutive 0s
Position 3 - 1 >=3 consecutive 0s
Position 4 - 3 >=3 consecutive 0s
Position 5 - 8 >=3 consecutive 0s

How can this information be used, along with bit-shifting patterns, to do the rank and unrank of a given bit combination.
This is another question where the ranking is based on "<=2" consecutive 0s; however what is now required is the opposite case, i.e. >=3 consecutive 0s.
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/162157/order-in-a-subset
Example -
N: 5 bits
k: >=3 consecutive 0s

00000 - k>=3 - rank - 00001 - unrank - 00000
00001 - k>=3 - rank - 00010 - unrank - 00001
00010 - k>=3 - rank - 00011 - unrank - 00010
00011 - k>=3 - rank - 00100 - unrank - 00011
00100
00101
00110
00111
01000 - k>=3 - rank - 00101 - unrank - 01000
01001
01010
01011
01100
01101
01110
01111
10000 - k>=3 - rank - 00110 - unrank - 10000
10001 - k>=3 - rank - 00111 - unrank - 10001
10010
10011
10100
10101
10110
10111
11000 - k>=3 - rank - 01000 - unrank - 11000
11001
11010
11011
11100
11101
11110
11111

Thanks.

Do you want to list the sequences with a string of $k$ consecutive $0$s or just count the number of them?  Note that when $N \gt 2k$ you can have two substrings of $k\ 0$s which you presumably only want to count once.  If $N=7, k=3$ you can count $0001000$ twice, once for the first three and once for the last three.

I want to list (rank/unrank) the full sequence. If ">=k" consecutive 0s appear twice or more in the sequence, they are counted only once as part of the rank. So given a rank, I want to find the exact sequence with ">=k" consecutive 0s.

Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/168140/755.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.  I have previously explained this twice: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/162157/order-in-a-subset#comment339055_162157.  Also, cross-posting when it has been answered elsewhere without disclosing that information is not terribly polite to readers.

To me, ranking implies some sort of order among the strings.  It appears you just want to list them.  Is that correct?

Given an "N" bit string with ">=k" consecutive 0s, I want to find its rank. And given a rank, I want to find the original "N" bit string with ">=k" consecutive 0s.
